# Only move cells within specified indexPaths

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, tableview

I have a tableViewController with some cells in the view. What I want to achieve is that the user can move certain cells, only within the indexPaths I've specified in an array.

Let's say I have these items:

1. Parent Item
2. Parent Item
3. Parent Item

   1. Child Item
   2. Child Item
   3. Child Item
4. Parent Item
5. Parent Item

I would like these "child items" to be editable and movable, but only within their boundaries. The user is not supposed to move these items outside their parent item.

I have figured out how to get only these items editable, and also movable. The problem is that I can drag these items outside their parent. I have the indexes of all the childs in an array called `indexOfCurrentSubViews`.

I see two solutions to this problem:

1. It's physically impossible to drag them outside of their parent. If you try to drag any further than to spot 0 (in their parent), they just stick and won't go any further.
2. If you happen to drag them outside, they just float back inside.

The problem is I don't know how to achieve any of these. Remember, all of these items are in one list. There aren't multiple Sections here. The only thing keeping track of what items are subitems and not is the array `indexOfCurrentSubViews`.

I tried creating an `if-statement` inside `moveRowAtIndexPath`to check if the `toIndexPath.row` is greater than the row of the last element in `indexOfCurrentSubViews` or smaller than the row of the first item. If so, make the indexPath equivalent to that smallest (or biggest) item in the array. And this works for placing them correctly in another array I have (to keep track of all the items in the view). But even though it's correctly placed in my array, it's still in the incorrect spot in the view.

How can I achieve something like what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement this `UITableViewDelegate` method:

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toProposedIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)proposedDestinationIndexPath
```

Basically, you need to determine if the proposed indexPath is valid. If not, then you need to return an alternate indexPath that is acceptable. If it is acceptable, just return the proposed indexPath.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I actually found this method in the documentation right after posting the question.

My (new) question is now, how would I implement this method to work with the array of index Paths I have?